# Neo4j, create relationships according to the order of the node property values

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a graph database. The nodes in the graph suppose to be connected based on the order of the given property values. For example, the graph nodes can be:

**(a{p:1}) (b{p:3}) (c{p:6}) (d{p:8})**

then the connections suppose to be:

**a--b--c--d**

according to the order of the p value.

Where the problem is that the p values are randomly given.

So, how can I create the relationships between the nodes by Cypher?

Could you guys give me any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds lik the goal is to organize the nodes by `p` and then create a relationship between them to establish the ordered list.

```
// find all of the nodes with a p value
MATCH (n:Node)
WHERE EXISTS (n.p)

// put them in a collection ordered by p
WITH n
ORDER BY n.p
WITH COLLECT(n) AS nodes

// iterate over the collection in pairs starting at the beginning and create the relationship
UNWIND RANGE(1,size(nodes)-1) AS idx
WITH nodes[idx-1] AS a, nodes[idx] AS b
MERGE (a)-[:NEXT]->(b)
```